# Finding how many numbers having 7 in them by using R

Tags: r

For n <= 1000, how many numbers have 7 in them?

```
count = 0  
for (i in 1:1000) {
## 1st digit, 2nd digit, 3rd digit: i%%10, (i%%100 - i%%10)/10 , (i%%1000 - i%%100)/100
# need short and smart code
count = count + 1
}
```

Comment: 8? 7? what do you want to say?

Comment: the downvoting seems a bit overzealous here: the op did include some code and showed what they tried (the modulus)

Comment: @user20650 I agree. Maybe post your comment before this getting closed.

Comment: @user20650 - Please post as answer.  It's a good one

Comment: cheers @David, Richard. I thought there may be a clever way without converting to character, but perhaps good enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl` to search for a specific character in a vector

To get the number of 7's in the vector

```
sum(grepl(7, 1:1000))
#[1] 271
```

To see the numbers you can subset, again using `grepl`

```
(1:1000)[grepl(7, 1:1000)]
```